# How to add/Remove Object at index swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have one array like

```
var arraybtnState: NSArray! = NSArray()
```

For add/Remove object into array, I had cast it in to `NSMutableArray`...

```
(self.arraybtnState as! NSMutableArray).addObject(button.tag)  
(self.arraybtnState as! NSMutableArray).removeObject(button.tag)
```

But it gives me `SIGABRT` error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x453e08) to 'NSMutableArray'

I have already tried `NSMutableArray` but it gives me error in below line

```
self.arraybtnState = self.strSubscribe?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

The question is what is preferred way to add/remove object in `array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it in a different way

```
var arraybtnState = [Int]()
arraybtnState.append(5)
arraybtnState.append(6)
arraybtnState.removeAtIndex(0)
```

While you declaring it like so

```
 var arraybtnState:NSArray! = NSArray()
```

you are creating pure `NSArray` type and it indeed cannot be casted to `NSMutableArray`

**UPDATE**

You can deal with it as follows

```
let some = self.strSubscribe?.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map{
    (var char) -> Int in
    return char.toInt() ?? 0
}
arraybtnState += some
```

Comment: check out the update...if i do this ....the error comes in `componentseperatedbycomma` line

Comment: error on last line `Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[(Int)]' and '[Int]?`

Comment: Maybe you adding it not to my code snippet variable? It works for me well

Comment: is `self.strSubscribe` a `String`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77616/discussion-between-bhavin-and-azat).

Answer (score 3):

An `NSArray` is immutable. Once created, it can't be modified.

That's the purpose of `NSMutableArray`, to be modifiable.

```
var myArr = NSMutableArray()
myArr.addObject("hey")
```

You also could use a Swift typed array:

```
var swiftArray = [String]()
swiftArray.append("hey")
```

### EDIT:

There's something screwy going on with the compiler. I think there's a bug in Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2.

This code should work:

let aString:String? = "One,Two,Three"
let array = aString?.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as NSArray

But it complains

> [String]? is not convertible to 'NSArray'

Suggesting that in Swift, componentsSeparatedByString returns a string array optional (`[String]?]`).

If that was the case, you should be able to fix it like this:

let array = aString?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")! as NSArray

But **that** gives this error:

> error: operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is '[String]'

Very strange.

If you look in the headers,  the Swift definition of componentsSeparatedByString() is

```
func componentsSeparatedByString(separator: String) -> [String]
```

It's pretty clear that componentsSeparatedByString() returns a Swift String array, not an optional. The compiler complains with either syntax.

This code **does** work:

```
let string1:String? = "One,Two,Three"
let array1 = string1?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
let aMutableArray = (array1! as NSArray).mutableCopy()
  as! NSMutableArray
```

That is your solution.

Comment: I tried `NSMutableArray`, but the problem is i also want to add this line....`self.arraybtnState = self.strSubscribe?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")`....and NSMutableArray gives me error on this line

Comment: or even `var array:[Int] = []`

Comment: That is a separate problem. If you make `arraybtnState` a mutable array (either a Swift var array or an NSMutableArray) then you can't replace it with an immutable array. That's what your code `self.arraybtnState = self.strSubscribe?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")` does. The method `componentsSeparatedByString` creates an immutable array. Change that line to  `self.arraybtnState = self.strSubscribe?.componentsSeparatedByString(",").mutableCopy()`.

Comment: @DuncanC it gives me error that string does not have member mutableCopy

Comment: See my edits. It looks like there's a compiler bug. AT the bottom of my edits I provide code that **DOES** Work.

Answer (score 2):

Please write in selected cell function. it is Automatically delete cell. when you select cell

arryName.remove(indexPath.row)

Comment: This one is what worked for me ; thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

`NSArray` is immutable. It can't be modified after declaration.

Create `NSMutableArray`, to be modifiable.

Remove Value at Index

```
someMutableArray.removeAtIndex(2)
```

This will remove the value at index 2.

Remove at End of Array

```
someMutableArray.removeLast()
```

Remove All Values

```
someMutableArray.removeAll()
```

Removes all values from array.