# Cannot add String to Array for PFUser

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have a button that pushes to a feed, I would like to record the name of the Feed Item in an array ("itemChosen") in my PFUser class every time the button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        PFUser.currentUser()!.addObject(feedItem.feedItemName, forKey: "itemChosen")
        PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            println(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("itemChosen"))
        })
}
```

I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'
```

If I use:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(feedItem.feedItemName, forKey: "itemChosen")
```

I can save the name as a singular String, but I want to append it into an array. Why doesn't addObject work and how can I fix it?

Comment: The _User class is better for LOGIN AND SIGN UP purposes. It would be to create a new class into parse then when you are ready to save data you only associate their id with that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if PFUser.currentUser()!["itemChosen"] == nil { PFUser.currentUser()!["itemChosen"] = [String]() }
    (PFUser.currentUser()!["itemChosen"] as! NSMutableArray).addObject(feedItem.feedItemName)
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("itemChosen"))
    })
}
```

The problem is that `PFUser.currentUser!["itemChosen"]` can be `nil`.

**Edit:** I found a way to do it using Xcode 6:

```
extension PFUser {
    var param: [String] {
        get {
            if let x = self["itemChosen"] as? [String] {
                return x
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
        set(val) {
            self["itemChosen"] = val
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    PFUser.currentUser()!.param.append(feedItem.feedItemName)
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("itemChosen"))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I tried this and what I get is an error on line 2 `'operand of postfix ! should have an optional type; type is () -> PFUser?'` -- so I remove the !, and I get the following error `'() -> PFUser does not have a member named 'subscript''`

Comment: @SamYoungNY sorry, forgot to write an initializer. Edited now.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I am getting the same errors

Comment: @SamYoungNY finally fixed. Now using `NSMutableArray` instead of `[String]`

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? Mine is v6.3.1 and I think that the next error I got may be due to this. After clicking button: `Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' to 'NSMutableArray'.` According to this post it may be Xcode related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190848/how-to-add-remove-object-at-index-swift

Comment: @SamYoungNY I'm using Xcode 7 beta 6 and the code seems to work

Comment: @SamYoungNY I found a way that must work in Xcode 6.

Comment: Yes this worked.. very impressive thanks again. Just so I understand... the extension basically tests: 'if there is a value in 'itemChosen', return x, else create an empty array, and set either x or 'else' as the type for val 'itemChosen'.. does that sound about right?

Comment: You're welcome ;) A bit wrong - if there is no value `itemChosen` for the user, it just returns empty array, doesn't actually set it to `PFUser`.